# Using the Sum function square the sums of numbers

Tags: summation, series-expansion

How do I use the Sum function for adding and squaring consecutive terms? It's an exercise from Wolfram Challenges.

I want to write my own function that uses the Sum function to get the sum of (1+2)^2 if the user inputs a two.  Or if the user inputs a three, then ((1+2)^2+3)^2).

Don't tell me the answer! A hint would suffice for the sake of a learning experience.

Also what kind of math should I look at to understand the soul of the exercise??

update!

```
Last@FoldList[Plus, 1, {a}]^2 

func[b_] := Last@FoldList[Plus, b, {a + 1}]^2 

Nest[func, Last@FoldList[Plus, 1, {a}]^2, 2] 

(1 + a + (1 + a + (1 + a)^2)^2)^2
```

I wanted that leftmost one to be a 2.

Comment: I think `Sum[]` is not going to work. Use the functions `Fold[]` and `Range[]` instead.

Comment: Does the exercise actually require the use of `Sum`?

Comment: @m_goldberg  no  the excercise  does  not  require Sum.  that  was  my  first guess at solving it via wolfram language.  however now i think  fold  or foldlist or nest is the way.

Comment: @Somos  Thanks for your advice.  I have made an update to my question using different functions.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want hints rather than an answer, so I will try give some. It would actually be easier to give the answer to such a simple problem.

Hints

- Use `Fold` with two arguments, a pure function as its 1st argument and a list as its 2nd.
- The list should be generated by `Range`; e.g., `Range[3]` to get the result when `func` is given 3.
- The pure function should be written in the form (previous_result + item_from_list)^2.